# What purpose does logging serve in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I understand how to create logs but to not understand what they are for. I see that they are like comments in your code expect they show up in run-time. Why would I create a log instead of a comment? What were they created to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logs can be very helpful in general debugging. For example when your application is stuck in, let's say, an infinite loop. You can then Log values to see what is actually going on and where in your application the infinite loop is occurring.

This holds true for every programming language, not just for Android. Comments are only used to clarify your code for other programmers, whereby logging can be a very powerful tool that speeds up your development process.

Comment: So you're saying it's like putting a print statement in my code for debugging purposes except it's show up in the ide instead of in the program.

Comment: Exactly. When you connect your Android phone or start an emulator, you should see a whole bunch of log messages in the Logcat overview in Android Studio. These are all informative messages originating from several applications on your phone, providing status information or other helpful debugging stuff. The reason they show up in your IDE instead of on your phone is because it would not simply not make any sense to show them on a phone.

Comment: Logging can also help to diagnose problems in any program when it's been shipped to users. If you receive a log file and you have used an adequate amount of cleverly placed log statements, you might get an idea of what went wrong.

Comment: I see. Everything I googled told me what logging does, but not why I would do it. I understand now. This is my first front end and back end development project so I have never seen or used this. Thank you.